# Align text next to a picture

Tags: html, css

How do I align the text as in the picture below?

```
 <div id="contact-info">
                    <div id="contact-list">
                        <div id="adresa">

                             <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png"  style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;">      
                             <p style="text-align:center;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74</p>
                             <p style="text-align:center;">,bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25,Cluj-Napoca,400609,Romania</p>

                         </div
                        <div id="telefon"></div>
                        <div id="mail"></div>
                    </div>

              </div>
```

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/2qa1ehk.jpg]

```
#contact-info
{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:url(images/BODY-CONTACT.png);
position:absolute;
right:0;


}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Fail to fix it as I want

www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

Comment: `text-align: left` on the "p" tag.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This is NOT the whole solution. I just gave you an idea about what approach should be used.

This is so simple ... For this you need to make `<p>` and `<img>` `position: absolute;`. like below

```
.centered {
   position: absolute;
   right: 12px;
   top: 110px;
}
```

and add class to `p`s and `img` like

`<p class="centered">....</p>
<img class="centered" src="...." />`

Try this using different `top` and `right` values for each `p` and `img.

Comment: Look how it looks now ... I want to be near the image text, more should be done this?

Comment: I just gave you an idea to how you should do it. Well You should use same approach for `img` and `p` ... Hope you understand my point !!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use div to nesting elements, in order to align them in a decent way. Also pay attention to the `display:block`or`inline`. You could read more in W3C docs. My touch to this problem is as follow:

```
<div id="adresa">
  <div id="addPadding" style="
    padding: 2em;">
    <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png" style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;display: inline;">
  <div style="
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    width: 80%;
">
 <p style="text-align:left;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,</p>
 <p style="text-align:left;">bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25,<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609,
<br>Romania</p>
  </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

I used 2`<div>`, one wrap the two `<p>` and the other one wrap the `<img>`and the new '' (or you can just simply add padding on the `<div id="adresa">`).

it will get a more similar layout result to your mockup, I wish I could took screen shot for you.

you just need to fix the `text-align:left` and margin on `<p>`tag to finish your job.

Comment: now is a space between the first and second row ... how can I get rid of it?

Comment: The space is from `<p>` tag's margin, one way to do that is to add the rule`margin-bottom: 0;` in both `<p>` tag style. And since there is already lots of inline style going on in your `<p>`  as well as `<div>`tag. I strongly recommend you give them a class and move them to your style sheet.

Answer (score -2):

Although the CSS purists would tell you not to, I would just add a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png"  style="width:22px;height:31px;">
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
             <p style="text-align:center;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74</p>
             <p style="text-align:center;">,bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25,Cluj-Napoca,400609,Romania</p>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not about being a "CSS purist", it's about having semantically correct markup and teaching someone "the right way" vs. "the easy way."

Comment: The "right way" is a matter of interpretation.  This is actually contact data that is being presented to the user. A picture is no less "data" than anything else, and by anybody's account tables can and should be used for presenting tabular data.  If I had to nest several tables together to present the data, then I would agree with that a div with CSS styles are best.  But when a simple table can do the job of a lot of complex css, easier is better.